# strange space coming between UITableView header and first row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, margin

**Edit :**

Now after removing autolayout it works only in smaller devices like iPhone 4,4s but it's not working on iPhone 6 iOS 9.1.2. If I add a blank section header of height 80 it works in iPhone 6. Still wondering what could be the issue ?

**Original Question :**
I have created a UIView subclass and created a nib for it as well.
I have assigned it to my tableHeaderView but the issue is in the nib my view's height is 200 pixels and in the code I need to manually set the height as 300 pixels. Here is the code

```
//Create and add header
self.header = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftMenuHeaderViewViewController" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];


self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 300);
self.header.target = (id)self;
// self.header.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.tblvLeftPanel.tableHeaderView = self.header;
```

Here are the screenshots

[image: HeaderView]

How it looks actually

[image: TableHeaderView]

Even tried these methods

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UILabel *sectionHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
sectionHeader.hidden = YES;
return sectionHeader;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 0.01f;
}
```

Autolayout images
Table View
[image: TableView]

Header View (No Constraints)
[image: Header View]

2 More screenshots
height 200 Px

[image: 200 Px Height]

Height 300 Px

[image: 300 px height]

It seems the issue is with autolayout

I have tried this code and it's working

```
 self.header = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LeftMenuHeaderViewViewController" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

 self.tblvLeftPanel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
 self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 200);
 self.header.target = (id)self;
 self.header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.tblvLeftPanel.tableHeaderView = self.header;
```

But getting Warnings in console how do I fix this ?

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that  you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView  property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fca1ca3f9b0 UITableView:0x7fca1b8fa000.height == 580>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca1c9aa8d0 UIView:0x7fca1c9aa290.bottom == UITableView:0x7fca1b8fa000.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca1c9aa920 UITableView:0x7fca1b8fa000.top == UIView:0x7fca1c9aa290.top + 20>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fca1ca409e0 UIView:0x7fca1c9aa290.height == 568>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
```

Comment: Do you have autolayout turned on by any chance?

Comment: yes and I'm using size classes. I have also wrote this in ViewDidLoad self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: Then this could very well be an autolayout artifact. Can you provide all the AL settings you made?

Comment: return nil in viewForHeaderInSection method

Comment: returning nil doesn't work

Comment: Try setting the header height to 0

Comment: If your view has height 200, and you set its height to 300, then it is not surprising that you see a gap of 100.

Comment: if I set it to 200 the header cuts out I am not sure why. To view the complete header I need to set it to 300.

Comment: @RudiAngela You were right the issue was with autolayout see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UiTableView has header space, you can hide this view by stretching it or hiding under navigation bar. Its size usually 64, so you need pull it 64 to top to make it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The above set of constraints is inconsistent: 
1- the table bottom == the view bottom
2- the table height == 568
3- the view height == 580
4- the view height == the table height + 20
This can never be accomplished.
The best solution IMO is to remove one of the constraints. Which one depends on which you consider least important.

Comment: I removed all the constraints and set the frame programmatically. It's working now.Still I want to use Autolayout so what constraints should I apply ? Post an example picture please.

Comment: Please start by testing on several screen sizes using the Simulator. This will help you determine how you want your views to adapt to the screen space.

Comment: Restriction on comments forces me to add a second one. Do you want the above UIView to adapt to screen size? If so constrain its top/bottom with respect to its superview, but not its height. You want fixed height then constrain its height and either top or bottom, but not both. Apply the same logic to the tableview with respect to the UIView.

Comment: You mean vertical spacing from top and Pin from left,bottom,right to 0